# Show the same ad in multiple locations on a page

Tags: ads, google-adsense

What service is used to serve the same ad in multiple locations on a single page load?

For example

[image]

It appears in this example Google is serving the ads, however I don't see an option for this in Google Adsense.

Comment: Probably not a good fit for this site. Maybe [webmasters.se] is better?

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happens in AdSense by chance, but the publisher cannot control it.  Well ordinary AdSense publishers cannot - I don't know if it's possible for the premium account folks, who have a lot more options.

And sorry, but I don't know any services that offer multiple ad-units from the same campaign per page.